# EL-Conditional operator ?: in composite component unexpected behavior

Tags: jsf, jstl, el, composite-component, conditional-operator

Wildfly 8, Jsf 2.2

If conditional operator `? :` in composite component is used with a list in a `c:foreach` loop, its behavior is not correct.

Output of example file is

```
eng germ ital
```

and not as expected

```
eng eng germ germ ital ital
```

If the composite component is rewritten as `ui:include` or `taglib` then the expected result comes.

File (test.xhtml):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/myComp"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:body>
   <my:testConditionalOperator languagesList="#{['eng', 'germ', 'ital']}"></my:testConditionalOperator>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Composite component (testConditionalOperator.xhtml):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="languagesList"></cc:attribute>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <c:forEach var="language" items="#{cc.attrs.languagesList}" >
            #{fn:length(cc.attrs.languagesList) gt 1 ?  language : "a"}
            <c:if test="#{fn:length(cc.attrs.languagesList) gt 1}">
                #{language}
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a Mojarra bug which doesn't manifest in MyFaces.

The work around is, set the size in `end` attribute and make use of `varStatus` to obtain it.

```
<cc:implementation>
    <c:forEach var="language" items="#{cc.attrs.languagesList}" end="#{cc.attrs.languagesList.size()}" varStatus="loop">
        #{loop.end gt 1 ?  language : "a"}
        <c:if test="#{loop.end gt 1}">
            #{language}
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</cc:implementation>
```

Note the EL 2.2 ability to just use `size()` instead of `fn:length()`

Comment: Thank you! It's weird bug. Should it be reported on Mojarra?

Comment: Now I have funny feeling to use conditional in composite components.

Comment: Yes, please. It's JSTL lifecycle related. It works fine with `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: java.net is offline. The new link to the issue is [https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4120](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4120)